# Why was this very low quality flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I've flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4591466/1841194) as very low quality. But I wonder how it was declined! It should be a comment not an answer also it is completely wrong!

Note that when I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25353683/1841194) it was approved and marked as helpful. In my opinion both answers attemps to solve the problem, but my question is why the first one was declined but the second one was approved?

Comment: No!  It is an answer!  Just crappy!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

But it's not a comment.  It's an attempted answer.

It may well be wrong, and if it is, then the proper course of action is to downvote it and optionally explain why it's wrong.

Answer should not be flagged just for being incorrect.

Comment: please see my updated question

Comment: @ABFORCE That flag shouldn't have been marked as helpful either, as the post did not at all qualify for deletion, as your flag is asserting.  One of the reviewers happened to edit the post when they saw it instead of just rejecting your flag, which unfortunately resulted in your flag being considered helpful even though it was an entirely inappropriate flag.

Comment: @Servy The first one was outright declined by a mod. The second flag went thru the VLQ review queue with the result being _Recommend Deletion × 3, Edit × 1, Looks OK × 1_ marking the flag as helpful.

Comment: @bluefeet I tried to find the review, but gave up after looking through 25 pages of history.  You guys really need to provide a better way for non-mods to find all review queue pages for a particular post.  Given that the post wasn't deleted, had no canned comments from the queue, and was edited made me confident enough to guess at what happened.

Comment: @Servy It's a sekrit :) But I agree without being a mod, it is difficult to find that. How about you `feature-request` that?

Comment: @bluefeet Been proposed before.  Multiple times (with subtle variations, generally being queue specific).